# Django. Значение переменной как имя свойства модели

Tags: python, django

От клиента приходит переменная содержащая имя свойства модели которое надо изменить. Какой есть способ подставить переменную в качестве свойства?

Пример:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        prop = request.POST.get('prop', '')
        new_data = request.POST.get('new_data', '')
        my_model = MySuperModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
        # Вот тут надо подставить значение переменной prop,
        # как имя свойства модели.
        # В виду того, что значение в prop превышает 20 разных вариантов,
        # делать проверку через if-elif-else кажется сомнительным.
        # ...
        my_model.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setattr(my_model, prop, new_data)
```